# Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes error in App Script with proper scopes calling Directory API

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an App Script project on a Google Sheet. The App Script function is triggered using the `onFormSubmit` function, so when a user submits a Google form, it gets added to the sheet, and ideally an email is sent. I wanted to perform a check of the email address and look up the user's name from their email address to make the message look nicer.

However, every time I try to call the Directory API I get the following error:

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.get failed with error: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
    at sendFormByEmail(Code:33:35)`

As I had the Directory API enabled under Advanced Serivces already I created a new `.gs` file to test. It worked fine. The exact same line of code in `test.gs` fails when run in `project.gs`, and I don't understand why.

Code snippet:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  // Remember to replace this email address with your own email address
  var email = "myemail@company.com"; 

  // load spreadsheet where results were added and init default vars
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var subject = "";
  var term_obj = 
      { 
        timestamp: 0,
        //object creation
      };

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  term_obj.timestamp = e.namedValues[headers[0]].toString();
  term_obj.termed_user = e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString();
  //more assignments

  // verify the user exists
  Logger.log("Termed user is: " + term_obj.termed_user);
  Logger.log(AdminDirectory.Users.get(term_obj.termed_user));
```

It also fails when I insert a static string of a user I know is valid. 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly` is listed in the scopes. `Admin Directory API` is enabled.
What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake - I had created the **trigger** on my non-admin account. I had to delete that formsubmit trigger and then re-create it on my superadmin account.